# Proving Existence and Uniqueness of Connection 1-Forms

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to solve this exercise from Lee's Riemannian Manifolds, but am getting stuck.  The problem is:  let $\{E_i\}$ be a local frame with dual coframe $\{ \varphi_i\}$.  Show that there exists a unique matrix of $1$-forms $\omega_i^j$ such that $\nabla_X (E_i)=\omega^j_i(X)E_j$

I began by writing $X=X^j E_j\Rightarrow \nabla_X E_i=X^j\nabla_{E_j} E_i=X^j \Gamma_{ji}^k E_k$ and then letting $\omega_i^j(X)=X^j \Gamma_{ji}^k$.  However, I don't think that this is fully answering the question...maybe it is, but I'm a bit confused because I did not use the dual coframe at all, and for the next problem I will have to show that $d\varphi^j = \varphi^i\wedge\omega_i^j + \tau^j$ where $\tau$ is the torsion $2$-form defined by the torsion tensor.  I would think that my answer for this question should help me in answering the next one.

Comment: You'll use the dual coframe if you write $\omega_i^j$ and not $\omega_i^j(X)$.